# Rails spring testunit Bad file descriptor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rails-spring

I'm trying to use spring 1.4.0 with rails 3.2.22/ruby 2.2.5, and doing :

`bundle exec spring testunit <test_file.rb>`

outputs this :

`/Users/igor/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/gemsets/<app>/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:7:in 'for_fd': Bad file descriptor - not a socket file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
    from /Users/igor/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/gemsets/<app>/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:7:in '<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in 'require'
    from -e:1:in '<main>'`

From what I gathered in the Spring source code, the faulty instruction is `UNIXSocket.for_fd(3)`, which should be the first available file handle, so why is it caught as a `Bad file descriptor` ?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks !